# how to send multipart unicode sms using python gsmmodem library?

Tags: python, unicode, sms, gsm

I can send any single part or multi part none Unicode sms message using python gsmmodem.
this is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

import logging

PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB2'
BAUDRATE = 115200
PIN = None

from gsmmodem.modem import GsmModem

def main():
    print('Initializing modem...')
    modem = GsmModem('/dev/ttyUSB2', 115200 )
    modem.smsTextMode = False 
    modem.connect(PIN)

    try:
        message = u'ننننننننننننن نننننننتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتتتتتت تتتتتتتتتت'
        modem.sendSms('09355666238' , message)
    finally:
        modem.close();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it sends one part Unicode messages (less than 70 characters) successfully but for messages with more than 70 characters is throw this error message :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gsmmodem/modem.py", line 631, in sendSms
pdus = encodeSmsSubmitPdu(destination, text, reference=self._smsRef)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gsmmodem/pdu.py", line 341, in encodeSmsSubmitPdu
pdu.append(userDataLength)
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

how i can send multipart unicode sms message using python?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the library, but Unicode strings are not bytes.  Try encoding them to bytes before transmitting.  UTF-8 is a good choice as it supports the entire Unicode range.

```
message.encode('utf8')
```

However, the error message indicates the library was trying to do an encoding, and failed to append the data length.  Perhaps the byte-encoded data internal to the library cannot exceed 255?  The length of your sample `message` is 277 bytes encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

The `sendSms` method takes a unicode string and automatically detects whether it can be encoded as 7-bit GSM-7 or 16-bit UCS2. For GSM-7, long messages must be split into 153 character chunks, and for UCS2 they must be split into 67 character chunks (because of the dual-byte encoding).

Unfortunately, the current [python-gsmmodem](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gsmmodem) on PyPI (version 0.9) tries to split **all** long messages into 153 character chunks, which will fail if the message contains any characters outside of the [GSM-7 range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38).

This issue was [fixed in Dec 2013](http://github.com/faucamp/python-gsmmodem/commit/814fb3b4c1b31aedd20efe5ff2bb6abb3fe236ff), but is not yet included in the current version of python-gsmmodem (which was released in July 2013). There doesn't seem to be any easy way to monkey-patch the fix, so it looks like you'd need to install the latest version from github if you really need to send multi-part unicode messages.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but for anyone looking for a solution, use the forked version of python-gsmmodem by [babca](https://github.com/babca/python-gsmmodem) (works on python2 and python3)

please remove already installed python-gsmmodem and install this module instead:

```
pip install python-gsmmodem-new
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using Python-gsmmodem for my application to send and receive SMS. Using Python-gsmmodem 0.9, I had some problems such as unicode encoding, timeout in connect method then I tried Python-gsmmodem-new 0.1, it seem thats those problem have been fixed in this version.